# There is always a Galois subfield

Tags: galois-theory

Let K be subfield of $\mathbb C$ s.t. $|K:Q|<\infty$. Prove that there is a subfield $L \subset \mathbb C$ with $K \subset L$, $|L:Q|<\infty$ and with L Galois over $\mathbb Q$.

I'm also given a hint to use the Primitive Element Theorem.

Here's what I got so far.

Let $\beta\in K$ be primitive, having minimum polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$ and roots $\beta_1=\beta,\beta_2,\cdots,\beta_n\in\mathbb C$.

Let $L=\mathbb Q[\beta_1,\beta_2,\cdots,\beta_n]$. Note $|L:\mathbb Q|<\infty$ by $n$ applications of the Tower Law.

Let $\alpha\in L$ be primitive with $\alpha'$ being another root of the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$, ie. $\alpha=A(\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_n)$, $A\in\mathbb Q[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$.

This setup I got with the aid of a solution but I don't know how to carry on from here. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ is separable and so the only thing you have to worry about is normality. Now using the primitive element theorem write $K  = \Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Then let $L$ be the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, so that $L/K$ is Galois.